# how can i add data from barcode scanner to Datagridview Row by Row

Tags: c#, datagridview, barcode

[this is my code to show the data in textboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCf6u.png)so am trying to make an Casher system but am having trouble showing the data Row by Row,evertime the user scans an item i want the datagridview to show it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [barcode scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25939687/barcode-scanning)

Answer (score 0):

try this
form load:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            /*form load*/

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column1", "qty");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column2", "price");


         }



        int RowIndex = 0;
        private void txtBarcode_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
            {  /* .....
                .....
                ..... Sql connection*/

                while (reader.Read()) {

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = reader.GetString(2);
                    dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = reader.GetString(3);


                    RowIndex++;

                }
                reader.Close();

            }
        }
```